# .NET Mvc and Web Api Filter Authorization, How and Where?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, vb.net

I have been reading and searching for a best practice for doing this.

I am "learning" about Web ASP .NET MVC and also Web Api 2.2.

I am in the point of Authentication and Authorization, I clearly understand the meanning and difference in one and another. My problem come with Authorization, I already know allow/deny access using  Filter and use Roles.

But beside that I dont know where to implement the logic for authorize to some user to do some action, or to see some data, for example:

A *user* is Authenticated already and have the role *Pilot*

This user enter to a **controller/action** for example **flight/getPassengers/1**

Where getPassengers is an action to retreive all the passengers for the flight #1

Let's imagine that the current logged user on the role Pilot wants to view the list of that flight because He is allowed to, but he can't see the passengers of all flights, for example **flight/passengers/3** the flight #3 is from another user **Pilot**.

Where is the best place to put this validation logic?

**Inside the action: getPassengers**? I don't think so, because if later in this controller (flight) we need validate if the same info belongs to the current user (pilot) we would have to repeat that piece of code (DRY)

So, maybe a Custom Filter?

I find an article ([here](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/security/authentication-and-authorization-in-aspnet-web-api)) but I am not Sure if is in there and How gets implementated. I have an Implementation, something like this:

```
Public Class CustomFilter
Inherits ActionFilterAttribute
Implements IActionFilter

Public Overrides Sub OnActionExecuting(filterContext As ActionExecutingContext)
    MyBase.OnActionExecuting(filterContext)
End Sub

Public Overrides Sub OnActionExecuted(filterContext As ActionExecutedContext)
    MyBase.OnActionExecuted(filterContext)
End Sub 
End Class
```

Is creating this type of Filters and after that using this  on Controllers/Actions the correct way to achieve this?

Or how is this type of logic handled?

Thanks for your suggestions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should implement a custom `AuthorizeAttribute` where you can encapsulate this logic. Just be careful in the way you implement them, try not to have several Authorize Filters. It could impact the perfomance of your application. Design a good one that can be used widely.

Comment: Thanks @kadosh-alejandro . Do you know if exist any article where I can find more info. Or tutorial. Thanks.

Comment: There are several articles all over the internet. Check this one [link](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/56fb14/custom-authorization-in-mvc/) and you will find the very basic implementation of an AuthorizeFilter. But, sometimes you also need some parameters for your Filter, in that case check this [link](https://mycodepad.wordpress.com/2014/05/17/mvc-custom-authorizeattribute-for-custom-authentication/). Just focus on the `AuthorizeCore(HttpContextBase httpContext)` method, this is were your custom logic will live.